# Git Push only working when connected to specific network

Tags: networking

This is a weird one, at least for me.
When I'm on my home network or the office network, I get the following error when pushing to GIT

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I tether on my mobile phone and use that network connection, the push is successful.

I was told to empty my local_hosts file in my .ssh folder, however that didn't resolve the problem.

For more context I'm working with Drupal websites on the Pantheon platform, and I'm using the lando CLI.
Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Comment: first step : does the name get correctly resolved in all 3 configurations ? easiest way is to run `ping <hostname of my remote>` and see if your system resolves it to an IP address. or use a tool like `nslookup` or `dig`

Comment: perhaps a DNS problem? Say, when you are connected to X network the hostname resolves to a given IP (the correct one).... but when connected to a different one, the same hostname resolves to the _wrong_ IP? Or maybe overlapping IPs and so you are actually connected to two different servers that are using the same IP.

Comment: I did a ping on the network that works and got an IP. I did a ping on the one that didn't and got an error...

Comment: @bren Then the problem is not related to Git/Drupal/PHP/lando at all. Just a local DNS or network problem.

Comment: I agree... Any pointers on how I can fix it? I'm a front end guy, networks and local DNS isn't really something I know a lot about... apologies if that sounds stupid but I am genuinely a bit lost hence reaching out for help.